# Photo Sphere viewer make browser slow

Tags: jquery, canvas, 360-panorama, photosphere, photosphereviewer

I'm using Photo Sphere Viewer to show 360 images. I have a menu on the bottom with other 360 images. When i click one of these images, the photosphere change the image in the viewer. After changing the image about 3 or more times, the browser become slow.

The method I'm using is "empty()" from jquery to erase the old panorama image and then load again a "photoSphereViewer" and i think that's the problem. For some reason, when i use empty doesn't remove the image on the cache and after a time it become slow. I know that exist a method to change the panorama with "setPanorama", but when I try, the console shows an error that PSV (the variable) is not a function.

```
        //here is the panorama add it to the dom
        $(window).load(function(){

                PSV = new PhotoSphereViewer({
                    panorama: '',
                    container: 'photosphere',
                    default_fov: 65,
                    mousewheel: false,
                    loading_img:'img/loader3.gif',
                    cache_texture:0,
                    transition:{duration:1500, loader:true},

                }); 

        });

        //then a function with ajax (im using php) that set the URL:

            $.ajax({

            type:'post',
            url:'query/menu_r.php',
            data:{consulta:consulta, codigoFull:codigoFull},
            success:function(data){

                ruta = "content/"+recinto+"/"+vista+"/cu"+silestone+"/"+calidad+"/";
                ruta = ruta+data;

                //vacío container del 360.
                //$("#photosphere").empty();

                PSV.setPanorama(ruta, null, true );



            }        
    })
```

With the old method (empty the container and add the new panorama) works, but I have this performance issue. So I need to find a way to clean the cache or set the panorama without create it again everytime. any idea? Thanks!!

Comment: I tried with a different library "Pannellum" and the same happen. After change 4 or 5 times the panorama 360 image, the browser become slow. I really don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

finally i found a solution. I let it here if anyone need it someday. I finally used Pannellum library and I talked with the author. He gave me a very simple and effective solution. Just loading one viewer and using a method like "addScene" and "removeScene" the garbabe collector doesn't load and everything runs pretty well. If someone needs more information, here is the thread:

https://github.com/mpetroff/pannellum/issues/763

Cheers!